# Select query or stored procedure in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables. I need to extract all the columns in the first table. Then I have to select the `max of id` that matches the `orderid` from first table. The below is my scenario:

```
First table                                      Second table

id Orderid Name                                  Orderid Status   
1  3       4                                     3       4
2  4       xx                                    3       5
                                                 3       4
```

Output should be

```
id Orderid Name Status
1  3       4    4
2  4       xx   -
```

Comment: Which status to select from the second table for each orderid from the first table? why the status 4 was selected for the ordedrid 3 and not the 5???

Comment: Lastly updated status ie 4

Comment: How can you tell that it is the lastly updated status?? is there any datetime  lastupdateddatetime field in the second table?

Comment: I think you missed id in the second table example ? There is no way how to tell which record is lately updated.

Comment: I need to fetch the last updated status of particular orderid..On the above example 4 is the lastly updated status

Comment: Yes.You are correct.@Arkadiusz

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the second table has a datetime (or something) that can be used to determine which row was most recently updated...

```
Select f.id, f.OrderId, f.Name, s.Status
From firstTable f
   left join secondTable s 
       on s.OrderId = f.OrderId
           and s.Updated =
               (Select max(updated)
                from secondTable
                where orderId = s.OrderId)
```

This will only work if there is only one row in s with that same `updated` value.  Better would be to use a primary key value in s if one exists...

Answer (score 0):

With `OUTER APPLY`:

```
select ft.*, oa.Status 
from ft 
outer apply(select top 1 Status 
            from st 
            where ft.Orderid = st.Orderid
            order by st.id desc) oa --here you should order by appropriate column to determine which is last row
```

Comment: No its not giving the expected ouput..Suggest me please.

Comment: Did you change ordering by appropriate column? Give me the data that is incorrect and proove why it is incorrect

Comment: Sir i have only two orderid in first table  but its give three..i need status for two rows only

Comment: Only two rows with orderid 3,4

Comment: Then my query could not return 3 rows...it will return exqctly the number of rows in first table

Comment: May be you place second table in place of first table? ft is first table, st is second table

Comment: No i have checked lot of times.Any how thanks a lot sir..i have wasted half day..Thank you so much. @Giorgi Nakeuri

Comment: Hey, here is the fiddle  prooving that my query works correct. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9c56a/1          your comments seems to be provocation?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this does the job

```
SELECT ft.id
    ,ft.OrderID
    ,ft.NAME
    ,min(sst.STATUS)
FROM ft
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT TOP 1 st.orderid
        ,st2.STATUS
    FROM st
    INNER JOIN st AS st2 ON st.id = st2.id
    ORDER BY st.orderid DESC
    ) sst ON ft.OrderID = sst.orderid
GROUP BY ft.id
    ,ft.OrderID
    ,ft.NAME;
```

I used the SQLfiddle from Giorgi Nakeuri for the table structure... i hope he doesn't mind.....by the way i didn't know about the SQLFiddle...great site